# Obtener campo modificado en PL-SQL de una tabla

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio de **PL-SQL** (Oracle). Y necesito que en un  `triger`, si modifico una tabla pues en otra inserte **el campo que se ha modificado**.

La verdad que no tengo ni idea de como sacar dicho campo... He estado intentando esto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER modificar_ventitas AFTER UPDATE ON ventas
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
Vnombre varchar(50);
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN

    END IF;
END;
```

Pero en el `if`, cuando quiero colocar el `select` no se que introducir para recoger dicha información. ¿Hay alguna **función**, o **excepción** o algo que me ayude en eso?

**Enunciado del Ejercicio:**

> Si se modifica la tabla de ventas se insertará el cambio en el log,
>   indicando el campo que se ha modificado, el valor anterior y el nuevo,
>   incluyendo la frase “el campo x se ha modificado a mano” (dónde x es
>   el campo en cuestión)

**Modelo Relacional:**

```
Clientes (id, nombre)
Vendedores (id, nombre)
Ventas (id_clienteFK, id_vendedorFK, importe, fecha)
Tabla_log(id,tipo,descripción)
Clientes_vip(id,nombre,fecha)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ir verificando cada campo de la tabla con la función `updating()`, que te devolverá `true` si el campo ha sido incluido en el *update*.

Algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_update_ventas 
 AFTER UPDATE ON ventas
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  Descripcion varchar(500);
BEGIN
  Descripcion := '';
  if updating('IMPORTE') then 
    Descripcion := Descripcion || ' El campo Importe se ha modificado a mano old: ' || coalesce(to_char(:OLD.Importe, '#,##0.00'), 'null') || ', new: ' || coalesce(to_char(:NEW.Importe, '#,##0.00'), 'null');
  end if;
  if updating('FECHA') then 
    Descripcion := Descripcion || ' El campo Fecha se ha modificado a mano old: ' || coalesce(to_char(:OLD.Fecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'null') || ', new: ' || coalesce(to_char(:NEW.Fecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'null');
  end if;
 /* Repetir lo mismo con otros campos */
 /* finalmente, alimentar la tabla de log */  
 insert into tabla_log....;
END;
```

Comment: ¿`coalesce` que es lo que hace? Tiene buena pinta el código, he pillado la idea en cuanto pueda pruebo y te comento o doy como respondida. Muchas gracias :D

Comment: [`Coalesce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffunccoalesce.html) es una función estándar de SQL que devuelve el primer valor no nulo que se le pase dentro de los argumentos. La idea acá es que si el campo es `null`, obtengas la cadena + `'null'`, y no el valor `null`, que haría que toda la concatenación sea `null`, pues, `'cualquier cosa' || null = null`, y entonces no quedaría mensaje alguno.

Comment: Genial, gracias por la explicación. He ajustado el código a mi necesidad, pero la lógica y el utilizar el `updating` de esa forma ( que la desconocía) me ha sido bastante útil. Muchas gracias.